# How can I make a property page always show up?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild

I'm currently extending a custom "Platform" for VC-2010 (it is extremely similar to the standard pipeline and mostly just swaps 'cl' for 'gcc') and have run into a problem with the property pages.

I can't seem to figure out how to force a property page to always be visible. This page is for a tool that will pretty much always be run on a special control file that has many different tools run over it (hence why I don't want to directly link it to the file type via the 'FileExtension' in my 'ProjectSchemaDefinitions' file). So far I've only been able to get property pages to display when I've added a file with the correct 'ItemType' as an 'Item' in the vcproj file.

How can I make it so that my custom property page is always displayed, regardless of whether there is a property group for it in the vcproj file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fresh look at the code this morning revealed the '[ProjectTools](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/690841/vsip-custom-properties-are-not-available-if-located-in-vs2010-msbuild-directory)' MSBuild item which seems to do exactly what I want.